# How to simulate Odometry Data in ROS?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a mobile robot. I want to simulate its movement between specific waypoints. Can anybody please tell me how I can simulate the Pose of the Robot in ROS?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195786/how-to-simulate-odometry-data-in-ros?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-24**:
Do you want to simulate an actual robot including odometry or do you just want to send fake odometry data from somewhere?

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-10-24**:
I want to send some fake odometry data to the robot so that I can debug the robot's behaviour

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-24**:
To the robot or to the ROS system as if it came from the robot. The first thing sounds quite robot specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If by simulate you mean visualizing your robot navigation, you can use [rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide)

---

Originally posted by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) with karma: 651 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1